# NetBeans IDE 7.2 - installation Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm having a problem configuring NetBeans to work with the Zend Framework.

English Error: ‘php.exe’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Polish Error: Nazwa '"php.exe"' nie jest rozpoznawana jako polecenie wewn©trzne lub zewn©trzne,
program wykonywalny lub plik wsadowy.

I added this to Path:

`;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5`

[image]

Configuration ZendFramework

[image]

WampServer v 2.2

[image]

**How can I fix this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your version of NetBeans? In 7.3 RC2 you can change the php.exe interpreter path in `PHP -> General` tab, like:

[image: Change PHP 5 interpreter]